# selenium webdriver : find a classname in a located element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I running into a problem where I need to find a non disabled button on a page but the buttons share the same class name whether they are disabled or not(also the same innerText). They do have an additional class added to them if they are disabled.

I need a way to select a element and check if it doesn't have the class for disabled buttons
Thanks

```
loginBtn = browser.find_element_by_class_name('c-shus-layout-bar__menu-button')
loginBtn.click()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you need to locate button element containing some class name, say `c-shus-layout-bar__menu-button` and not containing some other class name, say `disabled` you can use the following `xpath`:
`//button[contains(@class,'c-shus-layout-bar__menu-button') and (not(contains(@class,'disabled')))]`

Comment: Great, perfect fix!

Comment: It's my pleasure :)